# PHP library for native GWT RPC

Tags: php, gwt, rpc

I can't find solution for parsing GWT RPC request with PHP. Request has strange format. I need find specifications for that format (parsing and expected response) or working server-side PHP library.

Sample of GWT request:

> 5|0|5|http://tracker/gwt/war/trackingsystem/|6F50E78F07D452C741455B0CA20F764D|client.rpc.RPCApiInterface|getIssue|I|1|2|3|4|1|5|12|

Comment: Well, there's [GWTPHP](http://code.google.com/p/gwtphp/) which is aimed at doing exactly that. However, I don't know, how well it works, and if it's still compatible with current versions of GWT (?) Maybe you'd like to try it, and report back, if it works for you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just communicate with the server via HTTP requests and JSON?

Comment: For chris_l - This project is empty. I can't find any source code for it.

For Igor Klimer of course i can, but at this case i must use third party library in client side (GWT). But it is important for me do it on server side.

Comment: Try the section "external links" on the right hand side of GWTPHP's web page. It says "svn browse" and "download". It's not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Sources for this example are here GWTPHP-Helloworld. (http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=207256)